# What can cause a .sh file to not launch through this type of install?

Tags: shell, ubuntu, gnome, software-installation

I am using an Ubuntu 12.10/Gnome3 and was setting up PhpStorm using this tutorial http://devnet.jetbrains.com/thread/439389
The process involved copy/**pasting** the files into usr/local/PhpStorm-** (with granted access through use of "Alt+F2" and type "gksu nautilus") then creating a launcher on the desktop. The launcher says it does not exist though path seems correct and when I double click the phpstorm.sh file I open it (in default editor) rather than launching.

This has happened before in various attempts at making Linux my default OS and this seems to be my biggest issue, installing software not built into Synaptic or one of the installer software.

So my question is not only how do I fix this, but also how to understand what is happening so I can figure out on my own next time.

UPDATE: So I was able to launch in the terminal using

```
chmod +x phpstorm.sh
./phpstorm.sh
```

Then it set up a launcher via the new PhpStorm install in my Applications/Programming. Works for now but still not the easiest process.

Answer (score 1):

Looking *[here](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/download/index.html)*, it seems there is perhaps a slightly more straightforward method of installing -- you just download a tarball, unpack it, and execute a shell script inside.  I'd assume that if you had gone that root, the .sh would have been executable to start with; if not then that's the fault of the people behind PhpStorm.

When you are looking for help with something like that, first look for official documentation (ie, by the people who maintain the product) before you start scouring everything else.  Even if the official docs are sketchy and require clarification, you at least then know about them, and they should at least provide a perspective on anything else you may find.

Understanding how file permissions work (including the executable bit) is fundamental to using the system, but if you did not know about this, then you did not know about it; hopefully you do now.

With regard to avoiding hassles like this in the future, recognize that there is no way for the operating system to compensate for sub-par practices by individual software distributors.  It's up to them to make things easier for you the user -- if they are too lazy to do this, then you have to do some work yourself, unfortunately.